# R ggplot2 wrap long x-axis labels over multiple rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar chart (I used ggplot2, geom_bar), but the labels for x-axis are too long and overlap. I would like to keep them as long as they are, but I also would like them to be horizontally (not vertically, nor with an angle). Is there some way to wrap the long labels over multiple (at least two) rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of a way through `ggplot` directly.  However you can do something like this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x='really long label \n with a return')
```

With your axis labels to make them wrap at a length you choose.

Comment: That works really great! I don't know why I didn't think of it myself.. Thanks!

Comment: This approach is quick and convenient. For a more scaleable method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878974/auto-wrapping-of-labels-via-labeller-label-wrap-in-ggplot2