# Wrap long axis labels via labeller=label_wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels

I would like to automatically wrap my labels in ggplot2, i.e. insert line breaks of long labels. [Here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/labeller) is written how to write a function (1) for it, but sadly I do not know where to put `labeller=label_wrap` in my code (2).

(1) function by hadley

```
label_wrap <- function(variable, value) {
  lapply(strwrap(as.character(value), width=25, simplify=FALSE), 
         paste, collapse="\n")
}
```

(2) code example

```
df = data.frame(x = c("label", "long label", "very, very long label"), 
                y = c(10, 15, 20))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: Histogram with long label not wrapped]

I'd like to wrap some of the longer labels here.

Comment: why don't you apply the strwrap function to your labels outside of ggplot2?

Comment: I am new to R. How could I apply the strwrap function outside?

Comment: Please include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You don't need the `label_wrap` function. Instead use the `str_wrap` function from the `stringr` package.

You do not provide your `df` data frame, so I create a simple data frame, one that contains your labels. Then, apply the `str_wrap` function to the labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

df = data.frame(x = c("label", "long label", "very, very long label"), 
                y = c(10, 15, 20))
df

df$newx = str_wrap(df$x, width = 10)
df
```

Now to apply the labels to a ggplot chart: The first chart uses the original labels; the second chart uses the modified labels; and for the third chart, the labels are modified in the call to ggplot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Number of Participants") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") 

ggplot(df, aes(newx, y)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Number of Participants") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Number of Participants") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution appears to be very close to my problem. But what if every three graph has different labels? Do I have to define three different function(x) in order to use str_wrap?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you question. The second call to ggplot is the way to go. That is, apply str_wrap outside the call to ggplot. If you have other variables containing long labels, then apply str_wrap to those variables as well.

Comment: I think we are almost there, but I don't quite understand how to implement the str_wrap to all my variables, hence graphs (about 25) which have all different labels (see again example code above).

Comment: `scale_x_discrete(labels = str_wrap(c("label", "long label", "very, very long label"), width = 10))`

Comment: This is excellent @SandyMuspratt. Remark: define your dataframe with ``variable`` and ``value`` instead of ``x`` and ``y`` and it will become apparent that the syntax is ``scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))``, using ``x`` and not ``variable`` as I had incorrectly assumed at my first attempt.

Comment: In addition, you may want to add ``+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0))`` to align the labels to the left (in your example, the 3 lines look centered).

Comment: The big problem is that `str_wrap` turns factors to characters, so the level order of the factor is lost.

Answer (score 65):

The "scales" package includes a function very much like Claude's and Leonardo's:
wrap_format.

```
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Number of Participants") + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10))
```

Comment: The advantage of this compared to Sandy's solution is that this preserves factor order.

Answer (score 16):

Here is another way without reference to the library `stringr`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Number of Participants") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) lapply(strwrap(x, width = 10, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="\n"))
```

where the call:

```
lapply(strwrap(x, width = 10, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="\n")
```

does the work of splitting the labels dynamically. The result is the same as in the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21894897/2107731).

Answer (score 1):

(Hopefully) improving on @Claude's answer:

```r
get_wraper <- function(width) {
    function(x) {
        lapply(strwrap(x, width = width, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="\n")
    }
}

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Number of Participants") + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = get_wraper(10))
```

Comment: @Leonardo_Fontenelle  only one fonction is enough `function(x,width)`