# How to make my barplot by group instead combining the same items together

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-structures, bar-chart

I'm plotting the GO(Gene Ontology) analysis with ggplot2. There are 15 groups, each of them have 3 items. what I want is look like this:
[image]

But what I got from ggplot is like this:

[image]

as you can see, the groups with same item were combined together, they are too tight to be recognized. but I hope they can seperate, each of them are independent.

is there anyway I can realize that? Thx!

here is the data:

```
dput(t3)
structure(list(X = 1:15, GO = structure(c(4L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 
13L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 6L), .Label = c("GO:0002433", 
"GO:0006644", "GO:0006650", "GO:0007169", "GO:0007266", "GO:0008360", 
"GO:0033674", "GO:0038093", "GO:0038096", "GO:0051056", "GO:0051347", 
"GO:0090407", "GO:1901652"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "GO Biological Processes", class = "factor"), 
    Description = structure(c(13L, 4L, 2L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 
    1L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("Fc receptor signaling pathway", 
    "Fc-gamma receptor signaling pathway involved in phagocytosis", 
    "glycerophospholipid metabolic process", "immune response-regulating cell surface receptor signaling pathway involved in phagocytosis", 
    "organophosphate biosynthetic process", "phospholipid metabolic process", 
    "positive regulation of kinase activity", "positive regulation of transferase activity", 
    "regulation of cell shape", "regulation of small GTPase mediated signal transduction", 
    "response to peptide", "Rho protein signal transduction", 
    "transmembrane receptor protein tyrosine kinase signaling pathway"
    ), class = "factor"), LogP = c(-40.887821181404, -38.4419736211887, 
    -38.4419736211887, -43.8825656440477, -40.9658168441261, 
    -40.928738226587, -52.6082917563572, -50.1381337600203, -46.3514494215002, 
    -71.5496270612963, -67.9829155303795, -67.4635662792925, 
    -40.1994934987666, -36.6884206140971, -33.5740640802768), 
    Label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
    Pvalue = c(1.2947288298802e-41, 3.61431815145327e-39, 3.61431815145327e-39, 
    1.3104919452196e-44, 1.08189012276903e-41, 1.17831599603069e-41, 
    2.46438322354707e-53, 7.27555687363364e-51, 4.45195307925231e-47, 
    2.82080418123444e-72, 1.04012244840109e-68, 3.43901223333678e-68, 
    6.31693635444945e-41, 2.04917659044434e-37, 2.66646519778058e-34
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

and here is my code:

```
ggplot(top3, aes(x = reorder(description, -log10pvalue), y = log10pvalue, fill = Label)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  labs(x = "Description", y = "Log Pvalue") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Where is `top3` in your question?

Comment: I'd recommend facets for this - keep your plot as is and add `+ facet_grid(~group)`, or whatever your grouping variable is called. If you need more help - please share some sample data  reproducibly - `dput()` is best for that. Don't need the whole thing, but maybe all 3 items from each of 3 groups.

Comment: @Duck already updated

Comment: please use dput to add your data.  It is hard to read it in the format you provided - espcially since you have adjacent character columns spearated by spaces, with spaces within them too.

Comment: already use dput() for data sharing, thx!

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you, facet does makes it better, but also makes them not from the same start.

Answer (score 3):

There are two fundamental approaches you can use here: (1) without facets, or (2) with facets.  I personally prefer without facets in this case, but I'll show you both using your example data.

First of all, the data you posted does not contain the column `log10pvalue`; however, I will assume that we can use `LogP`.  Your dataset as shared is `t3`, so we'll use that convention here too.  The base plot is as follows:

```
ggplot(t3, aes(x=reorder(Description, -Pvalue), y=LogP, fill=Label)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge()) +
  labs(x='Description', y='Pvalue') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

From the look of it, only one `Description` value contains more than one `Label` in this dataset, but it will work for demonstrating the solutions.

## Pre-work notes

Before implementing solutions, note that your plot code can be simplified a bit.  Using `geom_bar(stat='identity')` is just a longhanded way of saying `geom_col()`, which creates the bars based on x and with height of y by default.  [You can read about the difference between the two geoms here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).

Secondly, instead of defining x and y, then flipping with `coord_flip()`, use of `geom_col()` can just be used to specify your discrete axis as `y` and your continuous axis as `x` to not have to flip the axes after.

I'll implement these conventions in both solutions.

## 1. Without Facets

Your code initially was almost right to show without faceting, but needed a bit of tweaking to get to look right.  There's a few things to consider here:

- **Bar width is not preserved.**  In your plot and the plot above, you can see that the bar width depends on the number of labels.  This means that a `Description` with one `Label` will be wider than the bars for a `Description` with more than one `Label`.  To fix this, you can use the argument `preserve="single"` inside `position_dodge()` to ensure that the width of the bars are equal regardless of number of Labels.  You also want to change to use `position_dodge2()` here instead of `position_dodge()`.  The difference is apparent if you switch, but basically `position_dodge2()` ensures that bars are centered correctly.
- **Labels are loooong.**  Unless you can abbreviate your `Description` names... these things are long and are taking up all your plot space.  What you want is to [wrap the labels of the axis text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878974/auto-wrapping-of-labels-via-labeller-label-wrap-in-ggplot2).  I like the usage of `wrap_format()` within the `scales` package here.
- **Bars are going "the wrong way".** You want to reverse the axis, which you can do by using `scale_x_reverse()`.

Combining these solutions we get the following without using facets:

```
ggplot(t3, aes(y=reorder(Description, -Pvalue), x=LogP, fill=Label)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve='single'), color="black") +
  labs(x='Description', y='Pvalue') +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=wrap_format(38))+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Not too bad.  To show exactly as the example you showed, you'll notice that the colors of the bars are connected to the `Description`, and not the `Label`.  You can just change the `fill=` aesthetic to fix this.  If you do that, you also need to set a `group=` aesthetic so that `position_dodge2()` will know on what basis to use for the "dodging" or it will not work.  The problem with this approach is that it is not clear what bar corresponds to what `Label`... you can probably address that with annotations, but regardless, here's what that would look like:

```
ggplot(t3, aes(y=reorder(Description, -Pvalue), x=LogP, fill=Description, group=Label)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve='single'), color="black", show.legend = FALSE) +
# you have to set show.legend=FALSE or it will be... bad
  labs(x='Description', y='Pvalue') +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=wrap_format(38))+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

## 2. With Facets

To use facets, you can take the code from above and add `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`.  A lot of people prefer `facet_wrap()`, but honestly I always find it's easier to use `facet_grid()` and specify using `.` notation if you want to have the facets arranged vertically or horizontally.  Here, we want them arranged vertically, and faceted based on `Description`.  You also want to make sure to include `scales="free_y"`.  If you left this out, every facet would include a space for every other `Description`... and it would look really bad.

Finally, I remove the facet label (since we already have axis labels enabled) by setting the theme element `strip.text` to be `element_blank()`.

```
ggplot(t3, aes(y=reorder(Description, -Pvalue), x=LogP, fill=Label)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve='single'), color="black") +
  labs(x='Description', y='Pvalue') +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=wrap_format(38))+
  theme_classic() + facet_grid(Description~., scales='free_y') +
  theme(strip.text=element_blank())
```

[image]

You'll notice your reordering by `Pvalue` does not work here.  The order of the facets is in the order in which the levels are set when `t3$Description` is converted to a factor.  You can solve this by setting `t3$Description` to a factor yourself with a specific order given to the `levels=` argument *before* your plot code.  One way to do this that utilizes `arrange()` and the `%>%` notation from `dplyr` and `tidyr` is the following:

```
# arrange by Pvalue
t3 <- t3 %>% arrange(Pvalue)
# create factor and set levels according to the way in which they appear
# in your arranged dataset
t3$Description <- factor(t3$Description, levels=unique(t3$Description))

# ... your plot code from above here again
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! but as you can see, one of my questions is the ones share the same terms are narrowed together. but in the example I showed, they are separated. the 2nd and the 4th are both "Cell Cycle Phase", but they are separated.

Answer (score 2):

From your provided data, I assume you grouping is represented by `Label`, and you want to arrange those next to each other, in order of decreasing statistical significance. You can achieve this by setting `X` (which has unique values) as a factor, with the levels ordered according to the order you want your bars in.

Typically, people use -log10 p-value for that, so higher values are more significant.

When you do this, you get something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
t3 <- structure(list(X = 1:15, GO = structure(c(4L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 
                                          13L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 6L), .Label = c("GO:0002433", 
                                                                                                  "GO:0006644", "GO:0006650", "GO:0007169", "GO:0007266", "GO:0008360", 
                                                                                                  "GO:0033674", "GO:0038093", "GO:0038096", "GO:0051056", "GO:0051347", 
                                                                                                  "GO:0090407", "GO:1901652"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "GO Biological Processes", class = "factor"), 
               Description = structure(c(13L, 4L, 2L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 
                                         1L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("Fc receptor signaling pathway", 
                                                                                       "Fc-gamma receptor signaling pathway involved in phagocytosis", 
                                                                                       "glycerophospholipid metabolic process", "immune response-regulating cell surface receptor signaling pathway involved in phagocytosis", 
                                                                                       "organophosphate biosynthetic process", "phospholipid metabolic process", 
                                                                                       "positive regulation of kinase activity", "positive regulation of transferase activity", 
                                                                                       "regulation of cell shape", "regulation of small GTPase mediated signal transduction", 
                                                                                       "response to peptide", "Rho protein signal transduction", 
                                                                                       "transmembrane receptor protein tyrosine kinase signaling pathway"
                                         ), class = "factor"), LogP = c(-40.887821181404, -38.4419736211887, 
                                                                        -38.4419736211887, -43.8825656440477, -40.9658168441261, 
                                                                        -40.928738226587, -52.6082917563572, -50.1381337600203, -46.3514494215002, 
                                                                        -71.5496270612963, -67.9829155303795, -67.4635662792925, 
                                                                        -40.1994934987666, -36.6884206140971, -33.5740640802768), 
               Label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
                                   4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
               Pvalue = c(1.2947288298802e-41, 3.61431815145327e-39, 3.61431815145327e-39, 
                          1.3104919452196e-44, 1.08189012276903e-41, 1.17831599603069e-41, 
                          2.46438322354707e-53, 7.27555687363364e-51, 4.45195307925231e-47, 
                          2.82080418123444e-72, 1.04012244840109e-68, 3.43901223333678e-68, 
                          6.31693635444945e-41, 2.04917659044434e-37, 2.66646519778058e-34
               )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

t3 <- t3 %>% dplyr::mutate(LogP = -log10(Pvalue)) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(Label, -Pvalue)
ggplot(t3, aes(x=factor(X, unique(X)), y=LogP, fill=Label)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 2, linetype=2, col="red") +
    labs(x=NULL, y=expression(-log[10] * ' p-value'))+
    coord_flip()+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq_len(dim(t3)[1]), labels=t3$Description)+
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>