# ggplot2 - multiple rows in axis-labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a additional question to [R ggplot2 wrap long x-axis labels over multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982743/r-ggplot2-wrap-long-x-axis-labels-over-multiple-rows) because of my problem with the

```
gsub(" ", "\n", levels())
```

I try to include it in the following R Code:

```
ggplot(ntry[!is.na(ntry$V138), ], aes(x=V138, group=1)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count", fill="#008000", width=0.5) +
geom_text(aes(label = gsub("\\.",",",scales::percent(..prop..)), y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -0.5, color="black", fontface= "bold") +
theme(axis.text= (element_text(face="bold", size="9", color="black")), axis.title = (element_text(face="bold", size= "9", color="black")), panel.background = (element_rect(fill="#FFFFFF")), axis.line = (element_line(color="black"))) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
xlab(" ") +
ylab("Prozent") +
ggtitle(paste(attr(ntry, "variable.labels")[grep("^V138$", colnames(ntry))]))
```

My goal is to get the x-axis-labels in multiple rows. I tried every point in my code I could think or imagine of the possibility it would fit. 
My main point I tried to integrate *gsub* was in the part of **theme(axis.text= (element_text(face** behind the third bracket.

It would be fabulous if someone could help me. I do not see the rigth option.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you want the "labels" argument in `scale_x_discrete` if you are trying to change the x axis tick labels.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20123502/2461552) for an example.

Comment: thank you very much :) unfortunately, some of the labels are now in false order or disappered.. 
but it fits better than anything before.
Maybe it is caused by the data frame?

Comment: after another try and the add of *levels* like in the first article above, it fits.
Thank you :)